# How to generate a random number in dart excluding a particular no.?

Tags: dart

So guys how do we generate a random number between a range but that shouldnt contain a particular no. in that range in dart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print random numbers from 0 to 999 except say, the number 100. 
Then the following code fragment will be sufficient.

```
import 'dart:math';
void main() { 
  var n = 100; 
  do { 
    r = rng.nextInt(1000);
  } while (r == n);
  print(r); 
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be while r!=n ?

Comment: No. The loop will exit only when a random number other than 100 is generated.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on requirements for time, and distribution of result, say you wish to preserve even distribution and want to avoid calling a new random number, and are using the range 0-2000 and filling in 100

```
import 'dart:math';
void main() { 
       var n = 100; 
       do { 
          r = rng.nextInt(2000);
       }
       if (r >= n){
          r++
       }
       print(r); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me show u an example;

// created my method to get random numbers and use wherever I want
// used math library to create numbers randomly and equaled to numbers. 
// now we have to check if it will contains 0 so we will call method again to create new random numbers list which one no including 0.

import 'dart:math';

```
int void randomNumbers() 
 {
   int numbers=Random().NextInt(10); 

 if(numbers!=0)
 {
   return numbers;
 }
 else
 {
    int newNumbers= randomNumbers();
    return newNumbers,
 }
}
```

so u can call that method created below in anytime to anywhere.

Comment: Is not there any performance issue here? What if `randomNumbers()` method always generates `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: We set a FlatButton and when pressed, the var "leftdicenumber" receives a random number betxeen 1 and 6:

```
  FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                
                  leftdicenumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                  
                
              },);
```