# Displaying random 10 elements from a list flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list fetched from a rest Api and stored it as above.

Then in my listview. builder where I display all items in the list, But I want to display 10 items at a go and they should be random such that whenever i refresh my page ill display a new list of items. I do not want to display along list simply because i want the users to click a see all button to view all the items in the list in a different page.My quetion is how can i go about it as what have managed to do is displaying only one item randomly,and make them random

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the below example. You can assign the response of API to `data` here.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47)),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final _random = new Random();
  var data = [
    'T 0',
    'T 1',
    'T 2',
    'T 3',
    'T 4',
    'T 5',
    'T 6',
    'T 7',
    'T 8',
    'T 9',
    'T 10',
    'T 11',
    'T 12',
    'T 13',
    'T 14',
    'T 15',
    'T 16',
    'T 17',
    'T 18',
    'T 19',
  ];

  var listToShow = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: Container(
          height: 75,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.refresh),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    updateDataInList();
                  });
                },
              ),
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 28.0),
                icon: Icon(Icons.all_inclusive),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    showAllData();
                  });
                },
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listToShow.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return Ink(
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(listToShow[i].toString()),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void updateDataInList() {
    listToShow = new List.generate(10, (_) => data[_random.nextInt(data.length)]);
  }

  void showAllData(){
    listToShow = data;
  }
}
```

[image: GIF demo]

Comment: The code is working perfectly but there is an issue as some of the records are duplicating them self

Comment: You can create custom method to generate a random number. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55934615/4788260)

Comment: `listToShow = new List.generate(2, (_) => data[_random.nextInt(data.length)]).toSet().toList();`