# Flutter how to random list on listview

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a `TextField` that when the User inputs value it updates the list view which works perfectly as done in the below code but I will like to add a shuffle button that when clicked will randomize the list on the `ListView`.

```
ListView.separated(
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Text(
                        data[index],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                controller: _controllerPassPhrase,
                onSubmitted: (value) => setState(() {
                  data.add(value);
                }),
              ) 



  InkWell(
                                                 onTap: (){
                                                   
                                                 },
                                                 child: Container(
                                                // padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                                  child: Align(
                                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                      child: Flexible(
                                                          child: Icon(
                                                            Icons.shuffle,
                                                            size: 20,
                                                          ))))),
```

My shuffle button should randomize list inside `ontap` in above code

Comment: see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476718/how-do-get-a-random-element-from-a-list-in-dart

Comment: also see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62142150/displaying-random-10-elements-from-a-list-flutter

Answer (score 0):

you can just shuffle your list members with `.shuffle()` , this sample code might be helpful:

```
    Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.separated(
                    separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(
                        child: Text(
                          data[index].toString(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    // controller: _controllerPassPhrase,
                    onSubmitted: (value) => setState(() {
                      // data.add(value);
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          data.shuffle();
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                          // padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    
                          child: Align(
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Flexible(
                                  child: Icon(
                                Icons.shuffle,
                                size: 20,
                              ))))),
                ),
              ],
          

  ),
```

the output would look like:

[image]